# How to download images in iphoneAPP from facebook and Picassa

Tags: iphone

Any one tell me about image downloading functionality in iphone from facebook and picassa.I am making application in it I want to make functionality for download selected images from picassa and facebook via my application.So what i have to do?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I would better suggest use the [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library for downloading the images from a url.

You will have to do the following:

1. Create a NSUrlConnection and implement the delegate methods
2. Pass the url in your request and you will get the data in -`(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`
3. You can then create a UIImage from this data using
   `UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:activeDownloadData`];

Comment: Thanks for reply friend.but If possible then would you explain me about face book url.Because if I have 10 photos in my face book account and I select 3 photos among them then after how can I make url for them?which content I have to take for making download url for making download functionality into my application.